# Подключение и запросы к mysql  в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем, возникла задача автоматически собирать данные из  Mysql.

Есть 20 серверов, на каждом из них Mysql (структуры таблиц БД на всех одинаковые).

Нужно чтобы скрипт подключался к серверам и выполнял определенный запрос.

Вопрос:

- Как лучше реализовать данную задачу?
- Можно ли выполнять `mysql_connect()` в цикле?

Кто что посоветует? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ага, а если завтра вам надо будет еще добавить 20 серваков? Вы еще строк в код дописывать будете? 
Исходя из вопроса - я его понял так - есть N кол-во серверов с одинаковыми по структуре базами, и вам необходимо с каждой базой сделать одно и тоже.
Тогда можно создать таблицу (хотя вам может и подойти и массив в файле), которая будет содержать настройки подключения к базе. 
Так вот псевдокод примерно такой

1. Получаем массив с конфигурацией подключений к серверам.
2. Проходим по данному массиву циклом.
3. В теле цикла создаем подключение. Делаем что-то с базой. Закрываем соединение.

Comment: Ответ выше не смотрели?

Comment: я писал свой ответ когда вашего не было

Comment: Так и сделал. Но скорость выполнения данного кода оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: 3 сервака прописал. Время выполнения 2,5 минуты=( не айс.

Comment: 2,5 минуты ( не айс - оценка относительная)
Что вы с базой делайте - какой запрос отправляете? уменьшение времени нада искать в другом как мне кажется)
Нужно побольше информации

Comment: На каждом из серверов есть таблица, пусть будет selling, в ней куча полей. Я выбираю только сумму значений  одного из столбцов.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array=Array( 
                     0=array('sname'=>'localhost','uname'=>'root','upass'=>'root','dbname'=>'name'),
    1=array('sname'=>'localhost','uname'=>'root','upass'=>'root','dbname'=>'name'),
    2=array('sname'=>'localhost','uname'=>'root','upass'=>'root','dbname'=>'name'),
    3=array('sname'=>'localhost','uname'=>'root','upass'=>'root','dbname'=>'name'),
            );
    Foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
      {
       $link= mysql_connect($value['sname'],$value['uname'],$value['upass']);
         mysql_select_db($value[dbname],);
       MYSQL_QUERY(); // тут запросы нужные
       mysql_close();
     }
```

Если проще и в цикле по 20 то так проще и быстрее, чем ответ выше.

ps может что с $value напутал по ключам, но суть не в этом, суть в ответе. значения подставь свои.

Comment: Я сделал так
$azs_arr = Array ('5.81.171.233' => '****','5.119.205.138' => 'skpadm','5.106.61.102' => '*****');
$dbname = "oc";


foreach ($azs_arr as $err => $key){

$link = mysql_connect($err, $key, $dbpassword);
и тд

Comment: Ну можно и так, можно +1 поставить еще :) И ответ принять.

Главное суть решения уловил.

Answer (score 1):

"Есть 20 серверов, на каждом из них Mysql(структуры таблиц БД на всех одинаковые)." - я не совсем понял зачем это нужно, но это не важно. А про такую вещь как репликация в MySQL вы не думали? Может оно лучше будет?

Comment: Идея интересная.
но, репликация не подойтет. Каждый из 20 серверов работает посвоему, добавляет свои значения(РАЗНЫЕ).